# Sweatalert delete confirmation return value true/false with button in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<script>
function deletealert(pubid)
{
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary   file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false                   
    },
    function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
                return true;
            swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
        } else {
               return false;
            swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

ASP.Net------

```
<asp:Button ID="delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" OnClick="delete_Click" />
```

c# codebehind---

```
protected void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        delete.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return confirmation('" + ID + "')");

        ID = (string)Session["ID"];
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from AvailableDevice where ID = '" + Convert.ToInt32(ID) + "'", conn);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
            Session["ID"] = null;
        }
    }
```

the script is not work. How can i solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing your script in .cs file like this.

```
ID = (string)Session["ID"];
    //you can put your script in the .cs file like this 
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + ID + "');", true);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from AvailableDevice where ID = '" + Convert.ToInt32(ID) + "'", conn);
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
                Session["ID"] = null;
            }
```